# GCP deploy cloud function failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, google-cloud-build, python-poetry

I was trying to deploy a GCP cloud function using git hub actions and I got this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'Creating virtualenv xxxxxx-nJ6OriN1-py3.8 in /github/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs' (from line 1 of requirements.txt)`

`Hint: It looks like a path. File 'Creating virtualenv retry-failed-reports-nJ6OriN1-py3.8 in /github/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs' does not exist.; Error ID: 0ea8a540`

Up until today, when all git hub workflows failed with this problem, my CI-CD pipeline was working as expected.

I was able to deploy the function manually using `gcloud`, it fails on cloud build step

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What's the content of your requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were using this command to generate the `requirements.txt`:

`poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes > requirements.txt`

However, this stopped working.

Now I tried this command and is working fine:

`poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes`